# Is it necessary to PROTECT .Call arguments?

Tags: c, r

I have a bunch of Rcpp code that I have to rewrite as an Rcpp-free C/C++ extension (due to its license) and fortunately it's not turning out as painful as I'd feared. But in the interest of writing the cleanest code, I want to make sure I'm not overusing PROTECT/UNPROTECT. The [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Garbage-Collection) doc mentioned that "It is not a good idea then to just PROTECT everything in sight..." so I'm trying to be dutiful.

So here's the thing I wanted to check. In reading all the examples of writing C extensions for R, I've seen lots of examples where the author protects the argument of a passed function, like this taken from [this article](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1099).

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <string.h>
SEXP helloC1(SEXP greeting) {
  int i, vectorLength, stringLength;
  SEXP result;
  PROTECT(greeting = AS_CHARACTER(greeting));
  vectorLength = LENGTH(greeting);
  PROTECT(result = NEW_INTEGER(vectorLength));
  for (i=0; i<vectorLength; i++) {
    stringLength = strlen(CHAR(STRING_ELT(greeting, i)));
    INTEGER(result)[i] = stringLength;
  }
  UNPROTECT(2);
  return(result);
}
```

The SEXP greeting got passed in as an argument, and the author immediately protected it. However, from [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Garbage-Collection) I noticed this bit:

> Protection is not needed for objects which R already knows are in use. In particular, this applies to function arguments.

So, for the sake of sanity checking, could someone tell me if these code examples where the authors PROTECT the passed-in arguments could be trimmed-down? If this is the case, I'll be able to make my code a lot cleaner.

Comment: You're [correct](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html) in your assumption that function arguments do not need to be `PROTECT`ed.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Any reason to add the [r-faq] tag before the post gets an answer?

Comment: There is a little more information in the subject [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#c-vectors).

Comment: @hrbrmstr It's not an issue at all. But usually the [r-faq] tags are added after the post gets an answer. (I may be wrong). I'll wait for the OP to clarify your comment. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: @nrussell, I read that page too, but it only talks about PROTECTing a SEXP that's allocated within the C code, which I know to do. The question is about whether its incorrect to PROTECT SEXP's that get passed into the function argument of the `.Call`.

Comment: The argument is coerced to "character" (STRSXP) which may allocate a new SEXP if it is not a STRSXP already and, thus, needs PROTECTion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Input arguments do not need to be protected, but you're misunderstanding one bit -- it's not the input argument `greeting` that's being protected, but the new `SEXP` generated by `AS_CHARACTER(greeting)` that's being protected.

It's a bit confusing because the `greeting` variable is immediately re-assigned, but effectively you now have `greeting` pointing to a brand new `SEXP`, and it's that new object that requires protection from the garbage collector.

Comment: I think you're right. I had taken out protections of my input arguments in hopes of cleanliness, and it looks like our team started getting segfaults. I guess when in doubt, just slap an extra protect on things.

Answer (score 10):

> I have a bunch of Rcpp code that I have to rewrite as an Rcpp-free C/C++ extension (due to its license)

You may need a (better) lawyer.  R itself is under the same license as Rcpp, so "avoiding" Rcpp gets you little as the linked aggregate is still GPL 2 or later.

*Edit:* And just for kicks, here are two simpler and shorter implementations of your function.  You may find them easier to read and use. No `PROTECT` dance in user space as Rcpp takes care of it all.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector  helloC2(CharacterVector v) {
  IntegerVector res(v.size());
  for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    res[i] = strlen(v[i]);
  }
  return(res);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector  helloC3(CharacterVector v) {
  return wrap(sapply(v, strlen));
}
```

They produce (of course) the same output of your function.

First, yours:

```
R> system("cd /tmp && R CMD SHLIB prot.c")
R> dyn.load("/tmp/prot.so")
R> .Call("helloC1", c("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
[1] 3 5 5 3
R>
```

Next, mine:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/prot.cpp")
R> helloC2(c("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
[1] 3 5 5 3
R> helloC3(c("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
[1] 3 5 5 3
R>
```

Comment: Well, no, I have to beg to differ with you on the lawyer thing. (And yes, we have lots of lawyers and people who do software audits, and they flagged what I had determined myself.) You can see a similar discussion [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254737/does-an-rcpp-dependent-package-require-a-gpl-license). R "scripts" can have any license they want, but linking to the Rcpp license contaminates your code, and we have intellectual property we need to protect.

Comment: i) The Rcpp license is a feature. It also happens to be the same as the license used by R. Hence ... ii) If you link to R, with or without Rcpp, you are still bound by the GPL.   Hence ... iii) May as well use Rcpp as it changes nothing on the licensing / usage terms and still makes your coding easier.

Comment: Thanks for the [link](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254737/does-an-rcpp-dependent-package-require-a-gpl-license) though; the second answer there is plain wrong and I will follow-up there.  The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: Again, I have to respectfully disagree, as do our lawyers. R.h and Rinternals.h specify LGPL 2. Rcpp.h states itself as GPL 2 instead of LGPL 2. And that extra "L" makes all the difference.

Comment: See the [R FAQ Questions 2.11](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Can-I-use-R-for-commercial-purposes_003f). Please read the whole answer.  The _spirit of the law_ is clearly GPL-2 or later.

Comment: So a minute or two with Google reveals your corporate affiliation.  These days most firms rather insist on being on good terms with Open Source authors, so I find these antics somewhat saddening.   I will raise this at the R Foundation board level.

Comment: Wow! I didn't mean for this to be a flame-inducing situation. I am a very pro-open source person, but my company needs to protect the IP of some algorithms that we have written to provide services to our clients. We are proud of being an organization that embraces OSS whenever possible.

Comment: We can take this off-line but you could for example work to have your organization [support the R Consortium](http://www.r-consortium.org).  My employer does.